# How can I reduce $((p \to r) \land (p \leftrightarrow q)) \to (p \lor r)$ to $p \lor q \lor r$ using the logic laws?

Tags: logic

*I'm using resemble symbol because I can't find a way to write the correct symbol.

This is from my after-class exam and the teacher sees that everyone in class can't get the answer. So he assigns this to everyone as homework but I still don't know how to do it.

This is what I can get and I can't see any way to go after this

```
((p -> r) ^ (p <-> q)) -> (p v r) ≡
        ¬((p -> r) ^ (p <-> q)) v (p v r)                                 COND
        ¬((p ^ ¬r) ^ ((p -> q) ^ (q -> p)) v (p v r)               COND, BCOND
        ¬((p ^ ¬r) ^ ((p ^ ¬q) ^ (q ^ ¬p)) v (p v r)                      COND
        (¬(p ^ ¬r) v ¬((p ^ ¬q) ^ (q ^ ¬p)) v (p v r)                       DM
        (¬(p ^ ¬r) v (¬(p ^ ¬q) v ¬(q ^ ¬p)) v (p v r)                      DM
        ((¬p v ¬(¬r)) v ((¬p v ¬(¬q)) v (¬q v ¬(¬p))) v (p v r)             DM
        (¬p v r) v ((¬p v q) v (¬q v p)) v (p v r)                        DNEG
        ((¬p v r) v (¬p v q) v (¬p v r) v (¬q v p)) v (p v r)             DIST
        ((¬p v r) v (¬p v (¬p v r) v q v (¬p v r)) v (¬q v p)) v (p v r)  DIST
```

[This is what the laws I have *sorry if you can't see it clearly or is that I'm using my phone photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m4x5.jpg)

If anybody wants to help me but can't see the laws I will write the law's name here

```
1. COMM    [p ^ q ≡ q ^ p] , [p v q ≡ q v p]
2. ASSOC   [(p ^ q) ^ r ≡ p ^ (q ^ r)] , [(p v q) v r ≡ p v (q v r)]
3. DIST    [p ^ (q v r) ≡ (p ^ q) v (p ^ r)] , [p v (q ^ r) ≡ (p v q) ^ (p v r)]
4. ID      [p ^ T ≡ p] , [p v F ≡ p]
5. INV     [p ^ ¬p ≡ F] , [p v ¬p ≡ T]
6. DNEG    [¬(¬p) ≡ p]
7. IDEM    [p ^ p ≡ p] , [p v p ≡ p]
8. UBDD    [p ^ F ≡ F] , [p v T ≡ T]
9. DM      [¬(p ^ q) ≡ ¬p v ¬q] , [¬(p v q) ≡ ¬p ^ ¬q]
10. ABSP   [p ^ (p v q) ≡ p] , [p v (p ^ q) ≡ p]
11. COND   [p -> q ≡ ¬p v q] , [¬(p -> q) ≡ p ^ ¬q]
12. BCOND  [p <-> q ≡ (p -> q) ^ (q -> p)] , [¬(p <-> q) ≡ ¬p <-> q]
```

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Hi, I guess you are not allowed to change the order of occurrences of propositional variables or change the way the parentheses are set in long OR-statements, right? Because then you might reduce the long expression somehow to a shorter one..at first sight, it seems you need another derivation altogether, as from your final line there doesn't seem to be a way leading you somewhere with these rules, if I understand correctly

Comment: @Ettore I'm not sure about that either. Maybe I do it wrong since the start.

Comment: In fact, it seems to me there is a problem at least in line 4. Am I right that you plug-in for 'p implies q' 'p and not-q'? That is of course not correct. We don't have a negation of the implication...that is just straight implication...so you need to use some rule to plug in 'not-p or q' for it, right?

Comment: Also, note that the two distribution rules always give some correspondence between AND and OR - statements...so at least it is not totally obvious to me how to interpret your use of it, where you only work with OR-statements. Did you intent to use associativity-rule instead? In any case, it seems that this rule can help you rearrange the parentheses, after which you can use the eliminative rules..

Comment: @Ettore Thanks for your advice. I'll keep your advice in mind and try other attempts to do it.

Comment: On the third line you use COND to rewrite p->r to p ^~r ... this is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making some mistakes with the application of COND, both on line 3 and 4 ... you rewrite something like $p \to q$ as $p \land \neg q$, but that is not correct: you can rewrite $p \to q$ as $\neg p \lor q$ ... it is $\neg (p \to q)$ that rewrites to $p \land \neg q$

But yes, other wise you're doing the right thing: rewrite conditionals and biconditionals so that all you have left are $\land$'s, $\lor$'s, and $\neg$'s.  Then work in any negations using DM, and now you have one big long disjunction .. just what you have ... except you made some mistakes so you'll havre to do this again.

Anyway, now you need to simplify that disjunction: use IDEM and ABSP to get rid of terms.  Also keep in mind the following two common patterns:

$(p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q) = p \land (q \lor \neg q) = p \land T = p$

(many books call this one Adjacency and have it added to their list of laws ... too bad you don't have it ... but as you can see: you can simulate it in just a few steps)

$p \lor (\neg p \land q) = (p \lor \neg p) \land (p \land q) = 1 \land (p \land q) = p \land q$

(another super common and useful one, and some texts have this one in the list as Reduction ... again, unfortunately you don't have Reduction in your list, but the above steps show to do it)